# AsyncStorage in use Class Model React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, class, javascript-objects, asyncstorage

This is how I define my class

```js
class GlobalUserModel {
  constructor(
    userName,
    userEmail,
    phoneNumber,
    refreshToken,
    token
    // isEmailVerified
  ) {
    // ! add gender and address and Id and isEmailVerified

    (this.userEmail = userEmail),
      (this.userName = userName),
      (this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber),
      (this.refreshToken = refreshToken),
      (this.token = token);
    // (this.isEmailVerified = isEmailVerified);
  }
```

This is how I tried to create my getters and setters

```js
getUserName = async() => {
  // return this.userName;

  try {
    let item = await AsyncStorage.getItem("UserName");
    if (item === null) {
      return "N/A";
    }
    return item;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error + " error getting user name");
  }
};

setObjectForKey = async(key, value) => {
  if (!key)
    throw new Error("Cannot set a value (" / value / ") without a key");

  return await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
};

setUserName(name) {
  this.setObjectForKey("UserName", name);
  // return (this.userName = name);
}
```

and if I un-comment the `// return this.userName` (getter) or return `return this.userName = name` (getter) I can get the name in the first loading of the app and once I refresh/reload the app the name disappears.

I want to many more getters and setters to save certain class attributes locally using AsyncStorage.

The above code gives me this error

```js
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {\_x, \_y, \_z, \_A}). 
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Comment: I export the newUser created during the user signing up and I access the new user created as this

const currentUser = newUser;
  const name = currentUser.getUserName();

Answer (score 0):

```
getUserName = async () => {
    // return this.userName;

    try {
      let item = await AsyncStorage.getItem("UserName");
      if (item === null) {
        return "N/A";
      }
      return item;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error + " error getting user name");
    }
  };
```

you can use

```
await getUserName ("UserName")
  .then(data => data)
  .then(value => {
    a state or constant = value
    console.log("yourKey Value:  " + value)
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

OR

```
getUserName("UserName").then((userData)=>{
  console.log(userData);
});
```

Comment: Answers are much more useful to the OP and to future people with similar questions if they explain what was wrong with the original code, and how the code in the answer fixes the problem.

Comment: I tried both solutions and it didn't work bro :/

with this 
  await getUserName ("UserName")
  .then(data => data)
  .then(value => {
    const item = value
    console.log("yourKey Value:  " + value)
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))

I get this error for await keyword --> Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts(1068)

and with this   getUserName("UserName").then((userData)=>{
  console.log(userData);
});

I get this error --> (method) GlobalUserModel.then(): any
'{' or ';' expected.ts(1144)